# Trying to Install 'Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle' for Eclipse Photon 4.8 - Error

Tags: eclipse, installation, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install 'Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle' for Eclipse Photon 4.8, but I'm getting a error 'An error occurred while collecting items to be installed'

Error Log :

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.google.gson,2.8.8.v20211029-0838.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\ABHINA~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile711705258960764106.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\ABHINA~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile711705258960764106.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.genuitec.eclipse.base.feature,1.11.0.202206271604.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\ABHINA~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8444135606234416013.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\ABHINA~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8444135606234416013.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.genuitec.eclipse.common.explorer.jdt.feature,1.11.0.202206271604.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\ABHINA~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9209221889659955107.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\ABHINA~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9209221889659955107.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.genuitec.eclipse.core.common.platform,13.0.2.202206271604.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\ABHINA~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile13863507673029382572.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\ABHINA~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile13863507673029382572.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.genuitec.eclipse.core.common.rss,13.0.2.202206271604.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\ABHINA~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile13472859385592784987.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: ....
```

I can see it's trying to verify the package's integrity with Signature from Temporary SignatureFiles - but Why it's failing? Can anybody Help?

Comment: Eclipse Photon is 5 years and 19 releases old, it may not be able to read the signatures on those newer jars.

Comment: In addition what greg-440 says, the mentioned plugin patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving which, if it "works", can cause issues and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). If you don't like the built-in themes, there are other dark themes that are more ergonomic and don't do this.

Comment: @howlger, can you suggest some other Dark Theme?

Comment: I prefer a light theme for ergonomic reasons. If you do not like the built-in dark theme (make sure to use the latest version of Eclipse which has improved a lot since), you might try for example the [Eclipse Spectrum Dark Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-spectrum-dark-theme) or another dark theme (as far as I know loadtime weaving is only done by this one company).